# C - Chomp questions

Tags: c

I'm trying to create the game [Chomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp). I am halfway through but pretty stuck.

The game will have 5 different functions. Pointers and structs are not allowed.

a) **initialize()** Initialize every position in the matrix to 'O'. No parameters or return value.

b) **print_board()** Prints the matrix. No parameters or return value.

c) **get_move()** Scan a move from the player (row and col) and "return" it with an array. Parameters: Information about whos turn it is (Player 1 or Player 2), and an array with two elements where the move coordinates will be stored. No return value.

d) **check_move()** Controls if a move is legal (not outside the matrix and not a position that has already been eaten). Parameters: The move that is going to be checked (row and col). Return value: Result of the control. <------ ???????

e) **update_board()** Updates the matrix. Parameters: The new move (row and col). No return value.

This is how far I have come and I am stuck at the **check_move()** function. I don't understand what I am going to return from that function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int height    =  4;
int width     = 10;
char matrix[4][10];


void initialize()
{
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
            matrix[row][col] = 'O';         
}



void print_board()
{
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            printf("%c", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    printf("\n");
}



void get_move(int player, int input[])
{
    printf("Player %d, make your move: ", player);
    scanf("%d %d", &input[0], &input[1]);
}



int check_move(int position[])
{
    int row = position[0];
    int col = position[1];

    if(row <= height  &&  col <= width)
    {
        for(row; row <= height; row++)
        {
            for(col; col <= width; col++)
            {
                if(matrix[row][col] == ' ');
                printf("Invalid move! \n");
            }
        }       
    }
}



void update_board(int x, int y)
{
    for(int xi = x; xi <= 10; ++xi)
    {
        for(int yi = y; yi <= 10; ++yi)
            matrix[xi-1][yi-1] = ' ';
    }


}



int main(void)
{

    int player = 1;
    int position[2]; 

    initialize();
    print_board();

    get_move(player, position);

    check_move(position);

    update_board(position[0], position[1]);

    print_board();



    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you would return true/fale (1/0) and act upon that.

Comment: Yay, nice indentation! (Really. Rare bird. :-))

Comment: Rename `check_move` to `valid_move()`; make it return `1` when the suggested move is valid, and `0` when it is invalid.  You can then write something like: `do getmove(...); while (!valid_move(...));`. You're going to need some more loops in the code, too.

Comment: fill the matrix as you say with some valid character 'O' then when it is eaten then fill the eaten parts with some invalid character, all of the parts eaten...when a player chooses a position, if there is no valid character there then it isnt a valid move yes?  I would also put that top left as another special character 'X' perhaps, if they choose that then you check for that character and instantly they lose.

Comment: Ok, instead of renaming that special character to something else than an 'O' I think I will make the player lose by checking if they enter 1, 1 as a move.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Do you mean that **check_move()** should return a variable, for example **valid**. And then I have to check if valid == 1 in every function before they execute any code?

I don't really understand how I return that **valid** variable. I can't type **return valid = 1;**?

Comment: "Pointers and structs are not allowed..." because.. ? (and in case no one told you, the parameter `int position[]` *is* a pointer, so you can toss the first of your restrictions out).

Comment: @H2CO3 Grats on your 100K, sir. Hard-earned the whole way.

Comment: @Whoz They are not allowed because I don't know how to use them yet and I was told to use arrays. I thought `position[]` is an array.

Comment: @H2CO3 And calling a kid 25 years my junior "sir" isn't easy, so you earned that too. Btw, your rhapsody performance is solid (deserving of better audio quality; I imagine live it was fantastic) . I never went past Chopin and Rach, and prefer Beethoven sonatas myself. Showed my wife, who was glad to know I wasn't alone as a cs/ce/math geek that played piano. Most impressive, seriously. Glad you have that.

Comment: @user2952320 as a parameter it is a pointer-type. If you haven't learned that yet I've a feeling you'll be on it very very soon, so just another class or two.

Comment: @WhozCraig I imagine, *sir.* And I appreciate the feedback. There has been an unfortunate accident involving some data loss, so the original, proper recording is gone :-( The video that's finally uploaded on YouTube was shot with my father's phone. One thing I must admit, there were some mistakes in the piece, but I hope it will be better over time. I now also feel less lonely since you let me know you're playing the piano too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should return a value from check_move, because it is prototyped that way, I assume you want to use the exit status somewhere? :

```
int check_move(int position[])
```

and you have an unnecessary `;` at the end of your `if`:

```
int check_move(int position[])
{

    int row = position[0];
    int col = position[1];
    int status = 1;

    if(row <= height  &&  col <= width)
    {
        for(row; row <= height; row++) 
        {
            for(col; col <= width; col++)
            {
                if(matrix[row][col] == ' ')  //removed ";" from end of line, otherwise, 
                {                             //printf will always be called
                    printf("Invalid move! \n");
                    return 0;
                }//also added brackets to force return if error (only need one error to return)
            }
        } 
    }
    return status; //added return status 
}
```

So, now in the main, you would do *something* like this to call `check_move()`:

```
int main(void)
{

    int player = 1;
    int position[2]; 

    initialize();
    print_board();

    get_move(player, position);

    while(check_move(position) != 1)
    {
        printf("Try again!\n\n");
        print_board();
        get_move(player, position);
    }


    update_board(position[0], position[1]);

    print_board();

    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so in **update_board()** I now have to check if **status == 1**, and if it is 1 I will execute the code. Otherwise I will do what?

Comment: Usually unless the return status of a function shows success, you do not execute the next item in the flow, you would indicate to user to try that input again (perhaps in a while loop).  See my  edit :)

Comment: But I can't check if **status == 1** in the other function because **status** is not a global variable, and I am not allowed to have any more global variables. But **status** doesn't have to be global because I return it, right? But the other function doesn't know what **status** is.

Comment: The other functions do stuff that is all checked by check_move().  i.e., It looks like you are using the check_move function to check status of the move, so just call the others in a loop (as I have shown), with `status == 1` as criteria for leaving before letting user move on.  Savvy?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I get it. But damn I have to take a pause because I'm getting so dizzy from all this code.

Comment: See additional comments in code, questions about how you are initializing variables in for() loops...  Oh, disregard, I see what you are doing, they should not be re-initialized, as you have done that with the function argument position[]. :)